# Find smallest Index of max in nested loop, with key strictly in 0th index

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

When finding the max value in a nested loop at a certain index, the key usually takes priority. If there are multiple max values at the key in the list where the max value takes in, then other elements in the nested list are used to find the index of the max.

Example:

```
my_list = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 7]]
print(max(my_list))
```

Output:

```
[2, 7]
```

However, I wish to find the smallest index of the maximum value in the 0th index, without any interference from other values in the list, and using optimised code.

Right now, here is what I am doing to achieve my goal, and it does not look like the most efficient way to do so.

```
my_list = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 7]]
maximum_val = max(my_list)[0]
for item in my_list:
    if item[0] == maximum_val:
        print(my_list.index(item))
        break
```

Output:

```
1
```

Can someone kindly give a more time-optimised form of what my current code does, without importing external libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking `max()` to find the biggest *list*, and `[2, 7]` is larger than `[2, 3]`, because lists are [ordered lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Don't compare lists. Use a `key` function to select the first integer:

```
max(my_list, key=lambda nested: nested[0])
```

This returns the element from `my_list` for which the value returned by the `key` function is the maximum. In case of multiple elements with the same maximum, the first such element is returned:

```
>>> my_list = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 7]]
>>> max(my_list, key=lambda nested: nested[0])
[2, 3]
```

Next, to get the *index* of that element, pass in indices to `max()`, and have the `key` function map those indices to a value to compare:

```
max(range(len(my_list)), key=lambda idx: my_list[idx][0])
```

So this takes a sequence of integers from 0 up to (but not including) the length of your `my_list` list, then uses the `key` function to return the first integer of the element at that index in the `my_list` list:

```
>>> my_list = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 7]]
>>> max(range(len(my_list)), key=lambda idx: my_list[idx][0])
1
```

Comment: Thanks! I assumed key in nested was always set to 0th index by default, thanks for clearing the misconception up!